# Automatic sharing of PDF generated reports online on email or any other place in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdf, java-ee-6, email-client

I have developed a Point of sale system for Mart in JAVA-SE using H2(embedded) database. Now i have requirement that my software could share daily sale reports with admin online, on email or on any other source, email first priority. I have no idea how it is possible. i want to design a function which could automatically send PDF generated report at a given time like at 11.00 PM.

Comment: Sorry, what is Mart? Why are you talking about Java SE and tagging it as Java EE? Can you be more specific about the application stack you are using?

Comment: @AlexNevidomsky, i have not much experience of this, i will try to be specific next time. thanks for guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basicaly a cronjob for generating and sending the report.
there are various java implementations for cronSchedulers available like [quartzScheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

or you could go for a os side solution and use the cronjobs of your server (works at least for debian)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate PDF using Apache PDFBox and send it using JavaMail.